# Role from JWT 401 unauthorized while using Authorized on controller

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, authorization, unauthorized, asp.net-authorization

I'm getting 401 unauthorized while using GET with JWT in header. For single role authorized doesn't work as well.

SecurityService.cs - Generated random key on creation. Role is taken from user instance.

```
private const int TokenExpirationInSeconds = 600;
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
public byte[] Key { get; } = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(128);
public string BuildJwtToken(User user)
    {
        var roles = new List<Role> {user.Role};
        var roleClaims = roles.ToDictionary(
            q => ClaimTypes.Role,
            q => (object) q.Name.ToUpper());

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud, _configuration["Jwt:Audience"] ?? string.Empty),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"] ?? string.Empty),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(TokenExpirationInSeconds),
            SigningCredentials =
                new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature),
            Claims = roleClaims
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var ret = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return ret;
    }
```

Program.cs - SecurityService is added as singleton. Authentication, authorization used.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration);
SecurityService securityService = new(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<WorkItDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SecurityService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<UserService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<RoleService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<OfferService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<CategoryService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ResponseService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<LocationService>();
builder.Services.AddCors();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityService.Key);
    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = key,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();


app.UseCors(options =>
    options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin());
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

CustomRoles.cs

```
public static class CustomRoles
{
    public const string Admin = "ADMIN";
    public const string Recruiter = "RECUITER";
    public const string User = "USER";
}
```

UserController.cs

```
[HttpGet("All")]
[Authorize(Roles = CustomRoles.Admin + "," + CustomRoles.User + "," + CustomRoles.Recruiter)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
{
    return Ok(await _userService.GetUsers());
}
```

Role.cs

```
public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public long RoleId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Images

[image: JWT]

[image: Response]

[image: Entering JWT into GET]

Comment: do you mean that you got 401 error when using the token in the request header to visit the action method?

Comment: Yeah. In every case I've tried it, the token should be valid because I set expiration for 300 secs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue about the 401 error.

[image]

In my side it's related with the `SigningCredentials` defined in the `SecurityService` and  the `IssuerSigningKey` defined in `Program.cs`.

You used `RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(128)` to generate a `Key` and use it to set `SigningCredentials` and define the `IssuerSigningKey`. And when I used a hardcode Key, it worked for me.

I used `IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThisismySecretKey"))` in the `Program.cs` and `SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThisismySecretKey")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)` in `SecurityService`.

[image]

Therefore, I compared the value of the key used in `Program.cs` and `SecurityService`, I found they don't have the same value. So I recommend you trying to hardcode the key first for testing, then check if it worked for you.

[image]

Comment: It is still saying on jwt.io that signature is invalid, but its altleast working. I ended by using key from configuration.

var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]));

Thank you

Comment: thank you for your response sir, and I'm glad that your code is working now : )